# Does order really matter in setting up various CURLOPT_XXX constant options in PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

While using cURL in PHP, we usually set various curl options through function curl_setopt(). I am curious to know whether order of different constant options matters or not. Do we really need to care of which constants must come before or after other constants?

Any difference?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you suspect it would make a difference?

Comment: @iainn yes because "`It appears that setting CURLOPT_FILE before setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER doesn't work, presumably because CURLOPT_FILE depends on CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER being set.`"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php#99082

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php#112326

Answer (score 3):

No, you can set them in any order you like.